# How to save a Boolean entry in a has_many through join Table

Tags: ruby-on-rails, has-many-through

I need to define a method/action in my LessonsController that I can call from the lesson show action that marks the lesson as being completed by the current user.  What does that controller method look like?

Here's the overview of my models:

```
User
   has_many :completions
   has_many :completed_steps, through: :completions, source: :lesson

Lesson
   has_many :completions
   has_many :completed_by, through: :completions, source: :user

Completions
   belongs_to :user
   belongs_to :lesson
```

My Completions Table looks like this:

```
   t.integer  "user_id"
   t.integer  "lesson_id"
   t.boolean  "completed_step"
   t.string   "completed_by"
```

I'm assuming in the LessonsController it looks like this

```
def complete_step
  self.completions.create(completed_step: true, user_id: current_user.id)
end
```

Routes info:

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
  namespace :admin do
  resources :users
  resources :coupons
  resources :lessons
  resources :plans
  resources :roles
  resources :subscriptions
  resources :completions
     root to: "users#index"
  end

devise_for :users, :controllers => { :registrations => "registrations"}

# Added by Koudoku.
 mount Koudoku::Engine, at: 'koudoku'
 scope module: 'koudoku' do
   get 'pricing' => 'subscriptions#index', as: 'pricing'
 end


 resources :lessons do
   member :complete
 end

 # The priority is based upon order of creation: first created -> highest      priority.
 # See how all your routes lay out with "rake routes".

  # You can have the root of your site routed with "root"
  root 'pages#home'

get '/dashboard' => 'pages#dashboard', :as => 'dashboard'

  mount StripeEvent::Engine, at: '/stripe-events' # prov
end
```

Here's my button link to make this functional.

```
<%= button_to "Mark this Lesson as Complete", complete_lesson_path(@lesson), method: :put, class: "btn btn-warning btn-lg" %>
```

Will this work or am I WAY off?  Thanks!

Comment: The error I get when I attempt this approach:  Couldn't find Lesson with 'id'=complete_step

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Keep this is the LessonsController, but change it in either of the following ways:

```
def complete_step
  current_user.completions.create(completed_step: true, lesson_id: @lesson.id)
end
# ~~ OR ~~
def complete_step
  @lesson.completions.create(completed_step: true, user_id: current_user.id)
end
```

Both of these assume that you've already set `@lesson` in the controller, probably in a `before_action :set_lesson`.

EDIT:

If you need a route suggestion, then assuming you have `resources :lessons` in your routes file, you can either use an existing route (likely `update`) or add a member route like this:

```
resources :lessons do
  get 'complete', on: :member
end
```

If you add a route, then you will need to add an action that looks like

```
def complete
  complete_step
  redirect @lesson
end
```

or similar, however you want to handle the response itself. You will also need to ensure that `@lesson` is set, so you should tweak your `before_action :set_lesson, only: [:show, :update, ...]` to also include `:complete`

Comment: Is this a private method?

Comment: any suggestion on the route for this?

Comment: It's up to you, I just kept the same structure that your question had. I did assume you were somehow executing that code in the LessonsController. Your problem was using `self` instead of either `current_user` or `@lesson`

Comment: Is there any particular advantage to this approach compared to establishing a completions controller?

Comment: It just depends on whether you are going to have a full fledged resource for completions. If so, then it makes sense to have a completions controller. If not, then keeping it in the lessons controller is cleaner. If you go with a completions controller, be aware that you will also need to explicitly pass the lesson_id in params, and will need to include it in the `create` call (tweaking @Hardik's answer to look like `create(completed_step: true, lesson_id: completion_params[:lesson_id])`)

Comment: Thanks.  I'm getting a rake route error now though.  ArgumentError: wrong number of arguments (1 for 0)

Comment: What does the relevant part of your routes file look like? (add it to the question, that will be easier to read)

Comment: Added it to the question.

Comment: It's definitely the member command causing the rake routes error.  If I delete the member, the error clears.

Comment: I'm sorry, I used the wrong syntax for the member route. I updated the answer. [Here's more information regarding member/collection routes](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#adding-more-restful-actions)

Comment: Finally, what's the correct path for this action?  I currently have complete_lesson_path(@lesson), but it's throwing a 'No route matches [PUT] "/lessons/1/complete"' error

Comment: The request coming in is a put, so the routes file needs `put` instead of `get` for that route.

Comment: The record has been created in my Completions table.  Now I just need to play around with the button if and else logic to check to see if the completed_step boolean is true.  Thanks for all the help!

Answer (score 1):

Please try with below code.in your completion controller

```
def create
  @lession = Lession.find(params[:lession_id]) 
  @completion = current_user.completions.create(completed_step: true, lesson_id: @lesson.id)
  redirected_to @completion
end
```

Comment: Would this be in a CompletionsController or in my LessonsController because I already have a create method in the LessonsController. @Hardik-Upadhyay

Comment: What's my route going to look like for that?

Comment: resources :completions

Answer (score 0):

You can also just pass `user: current_user` to the `completions.create` method instead of passing in the `current_user.id`

Something like   `@lesson.completions.create(completed_step: true, user: current_user)`